# Remove First Name and Last Name Required Validation from the checkout

Tags: checkout, shipping-address, form-validation

When I add the new address as a Loggined In Customer at the checkout by clicking add new address button,  I want to make fields First Name and Last Name unrequired.

I applied this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- Update first name field validation -->
                                                                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <!-- Update last name field validation -->
                                                                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Its working fine When I use visible true but when I use for the below code for validation it's not work.

Comment: i will add your code. first time set validation false then working done. you have already discussed. but when i am second set validation true and then apply Magento commands all then works for me. now, the checkout page's first name and last name also showing validation.

Comment: I mean to say I don't want any validation for first name and last name?

Comment: When I add this validation under firstname 
                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">30</item>

its also working fine but what I want not working

Comment: i will share my video link https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/26232104?key=1732126730ba8dc2e9580f4edb049c0c

Comment: In my case my customer is logged in , when I tried to add a new address then this not working please check it

Comment: you can also check this
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/26235829?key=ef28673a132fcabacbce1c42a2166de3

Comment: please check this https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/26251629?key=d9ac1ba315078c04de58105610978a6f

Comment: its not working on my side also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152317/discussion-between-mohit-vamja-and-rana-zain).

Answer (score 0):

You should change the validation of the fields in the popup. You changed only the validation of fields in shipping address.

In any case... do you know that these fields are require at billing address and database? You can't place an order without firstname and lastname.

This data is displayed in many places in Magento, such as:

- order history
- emails
- etc.